# How to set the exact spacing in and around title

Tags: sectioning, formatting, titlesec

A thesis I was working on requires the gap between chapter label and the top margin to be 75 mm, a 25 mm gap between chapter label and chapter title, and a 25 mm gap between chapter title and the text that follows.

**Can someone please explain what would be the best way to go about doing this?**

I tried the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{report}
\usepackage[lmargin=30mm,rmargin=20mm,tmargin=30mm,bmargin=22mm,
        headheight=3mm,headsep=12mm,footskip=13mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\bfseries \Large \center \setlength{\parskip}{0 mm}}{Chapter \ \thechapter}{25mm}{}[]
    \titlespacing{\chapter}{0 mm}{75 mm}{25 mm}
    \setlength{\parindent}{12 mm}
    \setlength{\parskip}{15 mm}
    
    \chapter{Introduction}
    <some text>
\end{document}
```

This results in:
[image: Result]

**Problems: Chapter label starts at 115 mm instead of 30+75=105 mm, gap between title and text is way too large (40mm instead of)**

Although the spacing between the label and title is more or less 25 mm (I'm still completely not clear how it's measured), the other spacings need to be corrected.

(This is my first time using LaTeX and I'm really facing a lot of difficulties, I need to get the formatting done so that I can get started with the content, else I'll have to go back to MS Word)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! 75mm is the distance from chapter label to top margin or to the physical top of the paper sheet?

Comment: @Bernard 7 mm from the top margin, with a top margin 30 mm wide (that's why the 30+75 = 105 mm)

Comment: That's what I obtain with the code I posted. The chapter title is at 130mm, and the beginning of text at 155mm. The values of `parskip` and `\parindent` are also required?

Comment: Yes, they are needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has to use the `[rigidchapters]` option of `titlesec`, which makes the spacing reserved for the title area a fixed length, and find the values for the length parameters  by trial and error:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{report}
\usepackage[lmargin=30mm,rmargin=20mm,tmargin=30mm,bmargin=22mm,
        headheight=3mm,headsep=12mm,footskip=13mm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[rigidchapters]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\bfseries \Large \center \setlength{\parskip}{0 mm}}{Chapter \ \thechapter}{
\dimexpr25mm-\baselineskip}{}[]
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0 mm}{61.2mm}{38mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{12 mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{15 mm}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Introductory}

In former days -- that is to say, once upon a time, there lived in the Land of Gramblamble, Seven Families. They lived by the side of the great Lake Pipple-popple (one of the Seven Families, indeed, lived in the Lake), and on the outskirts of the City of Tosh, which, excepting when it was quite dark, they could see plainly. The names of all these places you have probably heard of, and you have only not to look in your Geography books to find out all about them.

 Now the Seven Families who lived on the borders of the great Lake Pipple-popple, were as follows in the next Chapter.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wasn't aware of the [rigidchapters] option, but isn't there a more "elegant" way to do it, one without trial and error. Won't these values change if I go for some other font?
Trial and error would've been my last resort anyway, although without [rigidchapters]

Comment: I think the parameters in use depend on the value of `\baselineskip`  (which vary with the font size). Without `[rigidchapters]`, the exact positions of the chapter head elements depend on the contents of the rest of the page, because some vertical spacings on the page use `rubber lengths`, which may slightly vary. I particular, without it, I  could obtain `almost`the value of 75mm, but never exactly this value.